# Upstream message - iOS GCM

Tags: php, ios, xamarin.ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement Google Messaging in my app and server using  [Xamarin API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.iOS.GoogleCloudMessaging). The downstream messages (server to app) is working great, but i can't get the upstream working.

At server side i'm using PHP with XMPP library (JAXL), with that i can auth at GCM server and send messages to devices. I've registered to receive messages with this code:

```
$XMPPClient->add_cb("on__message", function($stanza){ 

        echo "new message";
        $data = json_decode(html_entity_decode($stanza->childrens[0] -> text), true);
        $messageType = $data['message_type'];
        $messageId = $data['message_id']; //message id which was sent by us
        $gcmKey = $data['from']; //gcm key;
        ...
        });
```

At client, i'm using the GCM api call *SendMessage*:

```
    public class SendClass : ReceiverDelegate
{
    public void SendMessage(string Message)
    {
        InstanceId.SharedInstance.Start(Google.InstanceID.Config.DefaultConfig);

        Service.SharedInstance.SendMessage(new NSDictionary("key", "value"), @"SenderID@gcm.googleapis.com", "Message");
    }

    public override void DidSendDataMessage(string messageID)
    {
        base.DidSendDataMessage(messageID);
    }

    public override void WillSendDataMessage(string messageID, NSError error)
    {
        base.WillSendDataMessage(messageID, error);
    }
}
```

The GCM API have two methods that should be called when the message are in the process of sending to server, *DidSendDataMessage* and *WillSendDataMessage*, but those methods are not called.

Can someone give me some tips here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problems. 
First you need to set de delegate of *GoogleMessanging.Config* to your class (that inherits from *ReceiverDelegate*), attention not from *GoogleInstanceID.Config*.

After that, you need to call the method *Start()* from the two libraries,*GoogleMessaging.Service* and *Google.InstanceID*. Then the magic is done:

```
        private void StartService()
    {
        NSError ConfigError;
        Google.Core.Context.SharedInstance.Configure(out ConfigError);
        GCMSenderID = Google.Core.Context.SharedInstance.Configuration.GcmSenderID;

        SendC = new SendClass();
        Google.GoogleCloudMessaging.Config Conf = Google.GoogleCloudMessaging.Config.DefaultConfig;
        Conf.ReceiverDelegate = SendC;

        Service.SharedInstance.Start(Conf);
        Service.SharedInstance.Connect(delegate (NSError error)
        {
            if (error == null)
            {
                GetToken();
            }
        });
    }

    private void GetToken()
    {
        InstanceId.SharedInstance.Start(Google.InstanceID.Config.DefaultConfig);
        InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token(GCMSenderID, Constants.ScopeGCM, new NSDictionary(Constants.RegisterAPNSOption, DevToken,
            Constants.APNSServerTypeSandboxOption, 1), delegate (string Token, NSError error)
            {
                if (Token != null)
                {
                    OnTokenReceived(Token);
                }
            });
    }
```